# How to get the last score per entity before measure (date) in a new measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I currently have a raw data table called `Score Table` which has three columns: (1) an entity ID, (2) a score, and (3) a date.

I also have a `Measure` for a single dynamic date (I can't use date slicers for this for reasons that I won't bore you with).

My goal is to have a measure tell me what the last score is before the date indicated by the `Measure`.

[image: Example Image]
I for some reason am unable to pull this off in DAX. Whenever I try to use `Calculate(` functions in DAX, I end up only pulling the final date in the `'Score Table' [Date]` column (not before the `Measure` date and not different by `ID`.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will be handy to see your current formulas and also how you get the 'Date'. something like ```LASTNONBLANK``` over a filtered date should work.

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto the dashboard actually selects an event in another table which has an associated date in a date column. That date is then used in the ```Measure```.

Answer (score 0):

I still miss some information to give you a specific answer, but something like this should work.

```
PreviousScore = 
CALCULATE(
    LASTNONBLANK('Table'[Score])
    ,FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar')
        ,'Calendar'[Date] < [YourDateMeasure]
    )
)
```

Note that I'm assuming you have a Calendar table to manage the dates (you usually want one of those in your model)